# How can I prove the following derivative?

Tags: derivatives, binomial-coefficients

I would like to prove 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\binom{x}{k}=\binom{x}{k}(\psi(x+1)-\psi(1+x-k)),~~~x>0$$
where $\psi$ is digamma function. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you know/accept $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z) \psi_0(z)$, or does this also need to be shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that, by the [logarithmic derivative formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative#Computing_ordinary_derivatives_using_logarithmic_derivatives),
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)\right)\\=\left(x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)\right)\left(\frac{x'}{x}+\frac{(x-1)'}{x-1}+\cdots+\frac{(x-k+1)'}{x-k+1}\right).$$
Now, recall the definition of [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom{x}{k}$ and the definition of  the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) $\psi$.

Answer (score 3):

First $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z) \psi_0(z)$, where $\psi_n$ is the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) of order $n$.  When $n=0$, $\psi_0$ is also called the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).  So, \begin{align*}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \binom{x}{k} 
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \frac{x!}{k!(x-k)!}  \\
&= \frac{1}{k!}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x-k+1)}  \\
&= \frac{1}{k!} \frac{\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \Gamma(x+1)\right)\left( \Gamma(x-k+1) \right) - \left(\Gamma(x+1)\right)\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \Gamma(x-k+1) \right)}{\Gamma(x-k+1)^2}  \\
&= \frac{1}{k!(x-k)!} \frac{\left(\Gamma(x+1) \psi_0(x+1) \right)\left( \Gamma(x-k+1) \right) - \left(\Gamma(x+1)\right)\left( \Gamma(x-k+1) \psi_0(x-k+1)  \right)}{\Gamma(x-k+1)}  \\
&= \frac{x!}{k!(x-k)!} \frac{\left( \psi_0(x+1) \right)\left( \Gamma(x-k+1) \right) - \left( \Gamma(x-k+1) \psi_0(x-k+1)  \right)}{\Gamma(x-k+1)}  \\
&= \binom{x}{k} \left( \psi_0(x+1) - \psi_0(x-k+1)  \right)  \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice streamline approach similar to that used by Eric.

Let
$$f(x,k) = \binom{x}{k}.$$
Observe that
$$\binom{x}{k} = \frac{x!}{k! (x - k)!} = \frac{\Gamma (x + 1)}{\Gamma (k + 1) \Gamma (x - k + 1)}, \tag1$$
where we have used the well-known result of $n! = \Gamma (n + 1)$.

Taking the natural logarithm of both sides of (1), we have
$$\ln [f(x,k)] = \ln [\Gamma (x + 1)] - \ln [\Gamma (k + 1)] - \ln [\Gamma (x - k + 1)].$$
Differentiating partially with respect to $x$ yields
$$\frac{\partial_x f(x,k)}{f(x,k)} = \frac{\Gamma'(x + 1)}{\Gamma (x + 1)} - \frac{\Gamma' (x - k + 1)}{\Gamma (x - k + 1)}.$$
From the definition for the digamma function $\psi (x)$, namely
$$\psi (z) = \frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma (z)},$$
the derivative, in terms of digamma functions, can be rewritten as
$$\partial_x f(x,k) = f(x,k)[\psi (x + 1) - \psi (x - k + 1)] = \binom{x}{k} [\psi (x + 1) - \psi (x - k + 1)],$$
or
$$\frac{d}{dx} \binom{x}{k} = \binom{x}{k} [\psi (x + 1) - \psi (x - k + 1)],$$
as required.